# Unable to open file in r mode fatal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Through terminal, I am trying to execute a program . I have to mention a file which is present in another folder while writing the execute command.

I have one folder in which my executable resides. That folder name is **apps.** and the file which I want to mention along with the execute command is residing in another folder named **"dataset"**. This folder is in apps folder.

Rightnow , I am in apps folder

and run this command

```
./executable -i ./dataset/filename
```

but this gives me this error though the file is present in dataset folder:

```
Unable to open file in r mode fatal
```

Comment: What happens when you execute `./executable -i dataset/filename`instead?

Comment: Have i got it right - the question is why _some_program_ cannot open _some_file_? Great, more details maybe? Make sure which one file it's trying to do, verify file/directory access permissions, etc, etc.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu  same error appears. I even placed the file in apps folder and still this error appears.

Comment: Do the file's contents appear on the screen when you execute `cat dataset/filename` ? If they don't, then you may not have access rights to the file. If you confirm that you **do** have access rights, may be the file is locked for exclusive use by some other process. You can use `fuse` to determine that.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu Using cat command, it do display file content..

Comment: Then the most likely reason is that your executable program has a bug. Is that a program from a repository or a ppa? Or did you compile it yourself?

Comment: Use `touch -- -i`. Plus, @BolucPapuccuoglu's latest comment. Our telepathic abilities are limited.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu it's a C program from which I made the executable

Comment: @keltar where do I have to use touch command? in apps folder?

Comment: It appears so. In your current working directory from where you calling everything else mentioned in question.

Comment: @keltar A file named i (of 0 bytes) is created on executing this command.

Comment: Not `i`, `-i`. And yes, that's exactly what it does. Who knows your mythical software, you passing `-i` as arg, it could try to open it if it is that weird - you're not telling us anything specific.